# Subfolder opencart session is lost when someone moves to root folder opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I installed an opencart folder within another opencart.

For example: www.rootopencart.com  (this opencart version is 1.5.6)
www.rootopencart.com/inneropencart  (this opencart version is 2.0.3.1)

If I put a product in my cart from inneropencart and click on checkout, everything working fine.
But if I put a product in my cart from inneropencart and click on another category of rootopencart form my website header and then check my cart of inneropencart, there is no product in cart. :(

Means till the user visting www.rootopencart.com/inneropencart session is working fine. But if user goes to www.rootopencart.com his sessions is lost.

Please Note: Only inner opencart has all ecommerce funcationality. Root Opencart is just a simple category, product view webiste means no cart no checkout.

Can anyone solve my session problem?